# How to change the properties of NavigaitonViewItems

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, navigationview

**MainPage.xaml**

```
 <NavigationView x:Name="NPPngv" x:FieldModifier="public">
       <NavigationView.MenuItems>
          <NavigationViewItem Content="Customer"/>
          <NavigationViewItem Content="Deliverer"/>
          <NavigationViewItem Content="Admin"/>
       </NavigationView.MenuItems>
       <Frame x:Name="contentFrame"/>
  </NavigationView>
```

Is there a way to change a property for each of the `NavigationViewItems`
For example I want set all the items to `IsEnabled=false` but I need it to be repeatable and with any number of items.

Is it possible to create an array of the items and then iterate though it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MenuItems` property returns an `IList<object>` so you could do this in the constructor of your `Page`:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    foreach (var item in NPPngv.MenuItems.OfType<NavigationViewItem>())
    {
        item.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your source code file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create any number of items,you can bind **MenuItemsSource** with a model.And If you want to enable or disable NavigationViewItem, you can make **IsEnabled** property in the model then bind it.

.xaml

```
<Page.Resources>
        <local:NavigationItemTemplateSelector x:Key="NavigationItemTemplateSelector">
            <local:NavigationItemTemplateSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ViewModel" >
                    <NavigationViewItem Content="{x:Bind Name,Mode=OneWay}"
                                    IsEnabled="{x:Bind IsEnabled,Mode=OneWay}" >
                    </NavigationViewItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:NavigationItemTemplateSelector.ItemTemplate >
        </local:NavigationItemTemplateSelector>

</Page.Resources>

<NavigationView x:Name="NPPngv" MenuItemsSource="{x:Bind NavigationList,Mode=OneWay}"​
MenuItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource NavigationItemTemplateSelector}">
      <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame"/>
</NavigationView>
```

.cs:

```
[ContentProperty(Name = "ItemTemplate")]
public class NavigationItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate { get; set; }
    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item)
    {
        return ItemTemplate;
    }

}
​
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        NavigationList = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>();
        NavigationList.Add(new ViewModel { Name = "item1", IsEnabled = false });
        NavigationList.Add(new ViewModel { Name = "item2", IsEnabled = false });
        NavigationList.Add(new ViewModel { Name = "item3", IsEnabled = false });
        NavigationList.Add(new ViewModel { Name = "item4", IsEnabled = false });

    }
    private ObservableCollection<ViewModel> NavigationList { get; set; }
}
```